# AVAudio background music not pausing

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, multitasking

For the audio I'm using

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Music" ofType: @"m4a"];

    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];

    AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
    self.audioPlayer = newPlayer;
    [newPlayer release];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    if (self.audioPlayer) {
        [self updateViewForPlayerInfo];
        [self updateViewForPlayerState];
        [self.audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
                           }

    [fileURL release];
    [super viewDidLoad];

                    }
```

and the plist "App plays audio" is set,
background sound plays when the home is pressed but the remote controls from the multitasking switcher or lock screen don't work, background audio can't be paused or forwarded/rewinded.

What's wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a few things to receive those event calls.

In your view controller add

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

In your app delegate add

```
- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent *) receivedEvent {    
    if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
        switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            //handle play button
            break;

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
            //handle rew button
            break;

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
            //handle ff button
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but still the same with those buttons, any other ideas?

Comment: Try moving the remoteControlRecievedEvent function to your app delegate and make sure your app delegate a subclass of UIResponder.